# Word VBA: Why is my macro leaving the first letter of its target word italicised?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to write a macro to change "In-vitro", "in-vitro", and their italic counterparts into just "in vitro" with no italics or hyphen. It works, but it leaves the "i" as italics. Weirdly, the exact same code works perfectly for other latin terms like "in vivo". Here is an excerpt from the code code with the "in vivo" bits included to show how it works for that, but not for "vitro":

(Note, we are editing with tracked changes turned on)

```
Sub latintest()

With Selection.Find
 .ClearFormatting
 .Text = "([Ii])n-vitro"
 .MatchWildcards = True
 .Replacement.Font.Italic = False
 .Replacement.Text = "\1n vitro"
 .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, _
Wrap:=wdFindContinue
End With
With Selection.Find
 .Font.Italic = True
 .Text = "In[ -]vitro"
 .MatchWildcards = True
 .Replacement.Font.Italic = False
 .Replacement.Text = "In vitro"
 .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, _
 Wrap:=wdFindContinue
End With
With Selection.Find
 .Font.Italic = True
 .Text = "in[ -]vitro"
 .MatchWildcards = True
 .Replacement.Font.Italic = False
 .Replacement.Text = "in vitro"
 .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, _
 Wrap:=wdFindContinue
End With

With Selection.Find
 .ClearFormatting
 .Text = "([Ii])n-vivo"
 .MatchWildcards = True
 .Replacement.Font.Italic = False
 .Replacement.Text = "\1n vivo"
 .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, _
Wrap:=wdFindContinue
End With
With Selection.Find
 .Font.Italic = True
 .Text = "In[ -]vivo"
 .MatchWildcards = True
 .Replacement.Font.Italic = False
 .Replacement.Text = "In vivo"
 .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, _
 Wrap:=wdFindContinue
End With
With Selection.Find
 .Font.Italic = True
 .Text = "in[ -]vivo"
 .MatchWildcards = True
 .Replacement.Font.Italic = False
 .Replacement.Text = "in vivo"
 .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, _
 Wrap:=wdFindContinue
End With

End Sub
```

The code is literally exactly the same, but one changes "*in vitro*" to "*i*n vitro" while the other changes "*in vivo*" to "in vivo", as intended.

Has anybody got any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: I run the code and it worked ok. Try to check word auto correction options, goto FILE->OPTIONS-PROFFING. You can also try on another computer. Share a  portion of your word document so we can try with it.

Comment: Afraid I wouldn't be able to share the document as it's unpublished science papers I work on. Managed to  get around the problem by re-formatting the method of find and replace which for some reason worked - will add it as an answer. Cheers for trying tho :)

Comment: FWIW, while I understand you can't share your _actual_ text, you should be able to create a text that exhibits the problem, but doesn't reveal sensitive info. Failure to do that just makes it harder for people to help you

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working just by changing the formatting of the replace-all code to the following:

```
  With Selection.Find
        .Text = "in-vivo"
        .Replacement.Text = "in vivo"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

and so on.

Basically just moving the `.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll` outside of the `With` block solved it for some reason. It does means having a few more "blocks" of each bit of this code for each different incorrect formatting of "in vivo" etc., which is a slight issue in terms of efficiency, but it's better than it not working at all so gonna stick with it.